# Cannot download cdemu from ppa on debian

Tags: apt, ppa

I tried the following:

```
user1@debian-desktop:/home/user1$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cdemu/ppa
Unofficial CDEmu packages
More info: https://launchpad.net/~cdemu/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: Die "Keybox" `/tmp/tmpknhcngga/pubring.gpg' wurde erstellt
gpg: /tmp/tmpknhcngga/trustdb.gpg: trust-db erzeugt
gpg: Schlüssel 423A2125D782A00F: Öffentlicher Schlüssel "Launchpad PPA for CDEmu" importiert
gpg: Anzahl insgesamt bearbeiteter Schlüssel: 1
gpg:                              importiert: 1
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
gpg: Keine gültigen OpenPGP-Daten gefunden.
user1@debian-desktop:/home/user1$ sudo apt-get update
....         
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cdemu/ppa/ubuntu lunar InRelease
Fehl:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cdemu/ppa/ubuntu lunar Release
404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::3e 80]
Paketlisten werden gelesen… Fertig                        
E: Das Depot »http://ppa.launchpad.net/cdemu/ppa/ubuntu lunar Release« enthält keine Release-Datei.
N: Eine Aktualisierung von solch einem Depot kann nicht auf eine sichere Art durchgeführt werden, daher ist es standardmäßig deaktiviert.
N: Weitere Details zur Erzeugung von Paketdepots sowie zu deren Benutzerkonfiguration finden Sie in der Handbuchseite apt-secure(8).
```

I think the important line is:

```
404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::3e 80]
```

Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a 404 because the PPA [doesn’t exist for Lunar](http://ppa.launchpad.net/cdemu/ppa/ubuntu/dists/). You ended up with a repository configured for Lunar (which is the currently in-development release of Ubuntu) because PPAs aren’t intended for Debian; since your installation doesn’t correspond to a release of Ubuntu, `add-apt-repository` defaulted to Lunar.

You shouldn’t try to use PPAs with Debian. See [the CDEmu instructions for Debian](https://cdemu.sourceforge.io/debian/).

Comment: Why does the command 'add-apt-repository' exist at all on debian than?

Comment: And why does 'add-apt-repository' try to add Ubuntu stuff? I thought Ubuntu is built on top of debian. But seems debian is also linked to Ubuntu stuff.

Comment: `add-apt-repository` can add any `apt` repository, not just PPAs. Ubuntu is based on Debian, yes, but PPAs are Ubuntu-specific and [shouldn’t be used on Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian). It’s somewhat unfortunate that `add-apt-repository` in Debian allows adding PPAs without at least warning about it.